# Relative path not working but absolute works

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, path

I'm trying to load an image to use it with canvas in node.js. Always getting a not found error. Here's the code:

```js
const Canvas = require('canvas')

async function execute() {

    const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(1080, 611);
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    const license = await Canvas.loadImage('../../data/media/images/license.jpg');
    context.drawImage(license, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

execute();
```

It somehow works with the path from the explorer (`P:\\bot stuff\\darling.js\\src\\data\\media\\images\\license.jpg`).

The thing that confuses me even more is that `const { color } = require('../../data/config.json');` works perfectly fine, and that in the same file...

Folder Structure:

[image: Folder]

Node.js Version 16.10;
Windows 10 Pro 21H2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior of `require(...)` is always resolved according to its own rules in the relative path of the file by the `require.resolve(...)` function.

However, `Canvas.loadImage`. Because it's loading part implemented in C, it can have different behavior than Node and has no context for the current js file location.

I recommend you to resolve the path based on `__dirname` explicitly.

Comment: That actually solved it. Using `src/data/media/images/license.jpg` works, thank you!